# How to stop UDF recalculating when workbook is opened?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a workbook to value my investment portfolio. It includes UDFs which scrape data from some websites where Excel's stocks data type is not available. The UDFs take time to calculate.

I would like the UDFs to run when I hit F9 but not when I open the workbook.
Is there something like "If running as part of loading up the workbook then do this"?

I have Calculation=Automatic and Application.Volatile(False).

One of the UDFs:

```vb
Function GetLSEPrice(ticker As String) As Double

Application.Volatile (False)

Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
Dim url As String
Dim y As Selenium.WebElement

url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/" & _
      ticker & _
      "/united-kingdom/company-page"

driver.AddArgument "--headless"
driver.Get url
Set y = driver.FindElementByClass("price-tag")
GetLSEPrice = CDbl(y.Text)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it;

Step 1) - Create a New Property in your Workbook - to count how many times the various UDFs are called

Step 2) - Add Code in the UDF's to Test that Counter

I've Added Code to the SheetSelectionChange Event (Just to help trigger the UDF's)

AS follows;

```
Public UDFCallCtr As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ThisWorkbook.UDFCallCtr = 1  ' Not Really Reqd
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
```

This is the UDF I've tested it with

```
Public Function UDFTester() As String
   If ThisWorkbook.UDFCallCtr > 5 Then  ' Change 5 to any value that works for you
      ' Put you Code here
        UDFTester = "Time is now " & Now()
      ' Done
   Else
      UDFTester = "NOT READY YET"
      ThisWorkbook.UDFCallCtr = ThisWorkbook.UDFCallCtr + 1
   End If
End Function
```

The following may help show where the code goes

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tin. I will try this out when I get a chance tomorrow. Two queries if I may:

Comment: 1. Does the first block of code go in the same module as my UDFs? WIll UDFCallCtr preserve its value between multiple calls? I guess it must be yes, otherwise the code doesn't make sense. I didn't know you could have variables that kept their value between calls - so I obviously need to understand this better.

Comment: 2. What does 'Public' do in front of the UDF definition? I have never used this before.

Comment: Public just makes it available to be called from anywhere - any module, form, sheet, etc

Comment: I've amended the answer with an image for where some of the code MUST go

Comment: Thank you Tin. That is all clear and works as expected. Unfortunately for me, it didn't quite solve my problem. While the UDF no longer recalculates unnecessarily (wasting my time) it updates its value to "NOT READY YET" which messes up my calculations. What I really want is to keep the old values until I force a full recalculation. I've figured out how to achieve this by dropping the UDF altogether and writing a Sub (called by a button on the worksheet) which updates each of the cells which needs updating. That's all just FYI - no more help needed for now! Thanks again.